# How to use Function keys as standard key in one app only?

Tags: mac, keyboard, function-keys

On my MacBook I have *use all F1 F2 etc. keys as standard function keys* option unchecked. I use FunctionFlip to map F3 from Expose to Spaces.

However I would like to use function keys as real function keys when working under virtualised environment like VirtualBox or VMware Fusion. Going to *System > Preferences* is not very convenient.

Do you now how to check *use all F1 F2 etc. keys as standard function keys* **only** when a specific application is active?

Comment: This question has good answers over at Ask Different: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49315/can-i-use-my-f1-f2-etc-keys-as-standard-function-keys-only-for-specific-apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I finally started to use [Palua](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/palua/id431494195?mt=12) and it is just great.</strike>

Paula is no longer available so I use [Fluor](https://fluorapp.net/) these days.

Answer (score 5):

**Use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html)**

This application can provide the exact functionality the OP asked for. user495470's answer about KeyRemap4MacBook was helpful in pointing me in the right direction. However, it's outdated and no longer works as written because KeyRemap4MacBook has been updated. It is now called [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html). It looks to be well-maintained and is free and open source software (not the case with BetterTouchTool mentioned in another answer which requires payment after 45 days).

**Setting it up**

First download and install the Karabiner application. Once installed, in order to remap the function keys as standard function keys, you will need to add a "Complex-Modification" in preferences. There are several of these complex modifications prebuilt and downloadable from the Karabiner website, but you can also write your own in json.

Use the following code and place it in a file (named something like "functionkeys.json") in the `~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications` folder. Once it is there, go to Karabiner preferences and click `Complex-Modifications`, then `Add rule`. You should see the text `Function Keys in Terminal Apps` and there click `Enable All`.

**How to change which foreground application causes the effect**

This code specifically provides function key standard functionality while using any of several terminal apps (and nothing when using any other app). This code also allows media key usage in terminal apps by using `fn + function key`.

While the OP asked about a generic specific application, VirtualBox was mentioned in particular. The below code could be changed to create the function key functionality in whatever application(s) was required by replacing the contents of each instance of `"Bundle Identifiers: [ ... ]"` with any application(s). (VirtualBox may be  `"^org\\.virtualbox\\.VirtualBoxVM"` although I haven't tried it.) Use the included Karabiner EventViewer to find the application identifier for any application desired, and then plug in the values.

```
{
  "title": "Function Keys in Terminal Apps",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Use regular function keys in terminal",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f1"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f1",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f2"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f2",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f3"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f3",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f4"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f4",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f5"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f5",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f6"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f6",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f7"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f7",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f8"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f8",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f9"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f9",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f10"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f10",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f11"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f11",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f12"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f12",
              "modifiers": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f1",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f1"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f2",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f2"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f3",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f3"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f4",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f4"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f5",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f5"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f6",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f6"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f7",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f7"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f8",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f8"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f9",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f9"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f10",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f10"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f11",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f11"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "f12",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "fn"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "f12"
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$",
                "^com\\.googlecode\\.iterm2$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyperterm$",
                "^co\\.zeit\\.hyper$",
                "^io\\.alacritty$",
                "^net\\.kovidgoyal\\.kitty$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to also make this work when for example `Shift` or `Cmd + Shift` is pressed? Like `Shift + F1` or `Cmd + Shift + F1` ?

Comment: @Motsel I had the same problem because I wanted that in Android Studio. What I did was  1. `Import more rules from the internet`. 2. look for `Function keys work as fn keys (instead of media keys)`. 3. Either import as it or `Edit JSON` and `ADD BUNDLE IDENTIFIER`

Answer (score 2):

Try combining [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) with [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/):

- Set the keys you want "flipped" with FunctionFlip
- Set up application specific keys with BetterTouchTool

Comment: This is a fantastic app combination!

Answer (score 1):

Grab [**IronAHK**](http://code.google.com/p/ironahk/) and use it to remap **ALL** keys instead of System Preferences (reason being is that it might conflict with system -> preferences), it comes with a makefile for compiling easily under Mono.

Then use it just like AutoHotkey:

```
#IfWinActive,,VirtualBox
F1::Send { F1 }
```

Comment: I cannot find any compiled version. Do I need to compile on my own ?

Comment: Currently they do not provide any, yes you will need to compile your own unfortunately. But they provide a makefile I believe.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative to Palua is [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <appdef>
        <appname>FKEYS</appname>
        <equal>com.vmware.fusion</equal>
        <equal>org.virtualbox.app.VirtualBoxVM</equal>
    </appdef>
    <item>
        <name>fkeys</name>
        <identifier>fkeys</identifier>
        <only>FKEYS</only>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN, KeyCode::F1</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP, KeyCode::F2</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL, KeyCode::F3</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD, KeyCode::F4</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_LOW, KeyCode::F5</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_HIGH, KeyCode::F6</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV, KeyCode::F7</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PLAY, KeyCode::F8</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_NEXT, KeyCode::F9</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_MUTE, KeyCode::F10</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN, KeyCode::F11</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP, KeyCode::F12</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F1, KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F2, KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F3, KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F4, KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ KeyCode::F5, ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_LOW</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ KeyCode::F6, ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_HIGH</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ KeyCode::F7, ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ KeyCode::F8, ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PLAY</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ KeyCode::F9, ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_NEXT</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ KeyCode::F10, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_MUTE</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ KeyCode::F11, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN</autogen>
        <autogen>__ConsumerToKey__ KeyCode::F12, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP</autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't an option that Apple or [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) provides.

However, the author of FunctionFlip has obviously been able to write code that allows for dynamic configuration of the function keys so it can be done.

I would [contact the author](http://kevingessner.com/contact/) of FunctionFlip, and ask if he could add the features you need. Namely, controlling function key behavior depending on the active application.

If you pledge to donate for the feature it might get implemented faster.

Otherwise, I don't know of any other programs that offer this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use AppleScript to toggle the state of the function keys:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
reveal anchor "keyboardTab" of pane "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
click checkbox 1 of tab group 1 of window 1
end tell
quit application "System Preferences"
```

In addition, you can make this app specific with the help of [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/). If written a small tutorial how to pull this of [here](http://rocketink.net/2013/06/toggle-function-keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use Fluor (https://fluorapp.net) app.
This app make change function key behavior per app basis.